# DisLocker Install Issues

Tags: software-installation

Trying to install dislocker and running into some challenges after I down load and unzip it and issue the make command I get a fatal error message Below

I'm new to Linux so I'm probably missing something basic, any Ideas ?

Thanks
Paul

```
~/Downloads/dislocker/src$ make 
cc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wconversion -DPROGNAME=\"dislocker\" -DVERSION=\"0.4.1\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DAUTHOR="\"Romain Coltel\"" -D__OS=\"Linux\" -D__ARCH=\"x86_64\" -D__ARCH_X86_64 -D__LINUX -I. -I/usr/local/include -fstack-protector -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O1 -c -o dislocker.o dislocker.c
In file included from ./dislocker.h:29:0,
                 from accesses/accesses.h:27,
                 from dislocker.c:28:
./encommon.h:34:26: fatal error: polarssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
 #include "polarssl/aes.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:115: recipe for target 'dislocker.o' failed
make: *** [dislocker.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your issue yet. I came across it as well and I solved it by installing the `libpolarssl-dev` library:

```
sudo apt-get install libpolarssl-dev
```

---

Why? [That's why](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=polarssl%2Faes.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) **;)**